Add Text to span complex field by Jquery
I want onclick event on <input> tag to display custom error in <span> placed tag just below it
I have many input readonly fields like,

<input class="form-control valid" id="OneOrder_line_items_0__Title" name="OneOrder.line_items[0].Title" onclick="clicked(this);" readonly="True" type="text" value="Burton T-Shirt" >

and span fields is (to display error like):

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="OneOrder.line_items[0].Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<name>, and, <data-valmsg-for>, are same in both tags
This is what i want to run
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked(item) {
        var id = $(item).attr("name");
        $('span[data-valmsg-for='+id+']').text('Your Text'); 
        //Here it is not working, if I hardcode it, $('span[data-valmsg-for="OneOrder.line_items[0].Title"]').text('Your Text'); then it works
    }
</script>

Can't understand what the problem is

The " around id is missing, try: $(`span[data-valmsg-for="${id}"]`).text('Your Text');

Welcome to Stack Overflow. As was mentione,d you need to wrap your value in Double Quotes so that jQuery knows what you are looking for. Presently, it is unwrapped and will not be read right.

Consider something like this:
function clicked(item) {
  var id = $(item).attr("name");
  $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + id + '"]').text('Your Text');
}

Notice the Double Quotes.
As you mentioned, this worked:
$('span[data-valmsg-for="OneOrder.line_items[0].Title"]').text('Your Text');

You can see how the ID, typed out, is wrapped by Quotes. The same has to be done for your script.
